# Pandas is not giving corr matrix for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use the DF.corr to get correlation of my data. But I am only getting correlation of the last column to itself. 
I have read other question where your datatype of each col should be numeric and I am doing that as well.

Here is the code.

```
class Correlations:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.score = []
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.read_data()


    def read_data(self):
        self.x = read_csv(self.filename,sep='\t',index_col = False )
        self.x.replace(to_replace = 'None', value = 0.0, inplace = True)            
        self.x.apply(to_numeric)

    def correlation(self):        

        return self.x.corr(method='spearman')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not reproduce. If I copy your example data above then run this:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
print df.corr()
```

I get this:

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  1.000000  0.078538 -0.014326  0.273707  0.222093  0.006823
1  0.078538  1.000000 -0.050930  0.163618  0.108258 -0.257071
2 -0.014326 -0.050930  1.000000  0.074747 -0.099014  0.460622
3  0.273707  0.163618  0.074747  1.000000  0.636578 -0.308201
4  0.222093  0.108258 -0.099014  0.636578  1.000000 -0.008964
5  0.006823 -0.257071  0.460622 -0.308201 -0.008964  1.000000
```

You're doing a lot of stuff at once by making a class right out of the gate. You should take a debugging step back and simply:

```
df=read_csv(filename,sep='\t',index_col = False)
df = df.apply(to_numeric) # pay attention to assignment 
df.dtypes #show what the types of the fields are
df.corr()
```

I'm suspicious the magic is in `df = df.apply(to_numeric)` as `apply()` returns a dataframe and does not do an inplace edit of your df.

This gotcha could have likely been avoided had you been iterating line by line in a Jupyter Notebook rather than trying to cook up a class before testing the steps.

Comment: Thanks ! but even if I just do this, its only giving 1x1 matrix with the last column: 



x = read_csv('FlattenMetrics_Excel.tsv',sep='\t',index_col = False )
x.replace(to_replace = 'None', value = 0.0, inplace = True)
x.drop('Build_APP',1, inplace = True)
x.corr()

Comment: what does `x.dtypes` give you?

Answer (score 1):

I tried pandas dataframe [`corr()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html#pandas-dataframe-corr)?

```
df.corr()
```

It gives back 2d matrix of each pairwise correlation.

```
      0         1         2         3         4         5
0  1.000000  0.078538 -0.014326  0.273707  0.222093  0.006823
1  0.078538  1.000000 -0.050930  0.163618  0.108258 -0.257071
2 -0.014326 -0.050930  1.000000  0.074747 -0.099014  0.460622
3  0.273707  0.163618  0.074747  1.000000  0.636578 -0.308201
4  0.222093  0.108258 -0.099014  0.636578  1.000000 -0.008964
5  0.006823 -0.257071  0.460622 -0.308201 -0.008964  1.000000
```